# Как сделать кнопку “поделится”?

Tags: java, android

Нашел ответ здесь:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Приложение name, скачивай от сюда - ссылка");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Поделиться"));
```

Это работает, но как добавить картинку? Желательно вообще View, потому что нужно чтобы на этой картинке менялось количество очков))

Comment: что вы хотите отправлять картинку или ссылку?

Comment: хочу отправлять картинку))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button shareButton = findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
         Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
         Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.test/*"); 
         try { 
             InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(screenshotUri);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         } 
         sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
         sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
     } 
});
```